# Parsing data through parameters in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database

Can we append to a data from we are getting mySQL through Java.

Data table is like follow,

```
+----+-------------------+
| ID |      Desc         |
+----+-------------------+
| 1  | personal email %s |
| 2  | office email %s   |
+----+-------------------+
```

Can we change this `%s` in to a data through a method and print the output,

like-
    Printdata(String name)
    {}

and get the output

```
personal email test@test.com etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can do it.
Please check the below sample main program.

```
package com;

public class TestFormat {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String s= "personal email %s";
            String email = "test@test.com";
            System.out.printf(String.format(s,email));
    }

}
```